# Ember data - calling super on find()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:3916
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.7.0-beta.1+canary.3d383376 ember.js:3916
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88 ember.js:3916
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2 ember.js:3916
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2 ember.js:3916
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I'm starting a very simple application and trying out ember-data. I'm not sure if this is a bug or something I'm doing wrong. In my route and model function I have `@store.find('post', 1)` which works great. But if I try changing this to find all my records with `@store.find('post')` I get this error `Error while loading route: posts No model was found for 'super' Error: No model was found for 'super'` I don't know what **super** is and why would I need a **super** model? The error is coming from the function called `modelFor:` on line **9797** in ember.data.js. If I place a `console.log(key)` in this function I get the following output `post`, `App.Post`, `super`.

Below is the code I've got currently, its very basic:

**App.Post**

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
    title: DS.attr('string')
    description: DS.attr('string')
```

**Router**

```
App.Router.map () ->
   @resource 'posts'
```

**Index Route**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    beforeModel: () ->
        @transitionTo 'posts',
```

**Post Route**

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: () ->
        @store.find('post')
```

**Adapter/Serializer**

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter 

App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer
```

**RESTAdapter**

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
    namespace: 'api/v1'
```

Hopefully someone can help me spot the error or bug.

Comment: What's the data that comes back from your server when you call `find('post')`, will you show your adapter/serializer as well

Comment: Its not even calling the server as it errors first with the error I've mentioned in my question. I've only included my adapter/serializer as follows: `App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter` and `App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer`

Comment: okay, will you show your router as well

Comment: Thanks. The router is in my question. `Post Route`. Is that what your asking for?

Comment: It generally looks like this 
App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});, here's an example http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/151/edit

Comment: Thanks. Ok I've added that. Under `Router`

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing an issue, or reproducing it not working, here's a working version of roughly the same code you're using, maybe you'll be able to spot some extra code you have that may be causing an issue, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/458/edit

Comment: Thanks for that. I decided to comment everything out and start adding code back in. I found the problem I've got this to prefix my namespace globally. Can you tell me what I've done wrong? `DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
  namespace: 'api/v1'`

Comment: OK...I know where its breaking now. If I remove the `1` from the namespace so it becomes `namespace: 'api/v'` it will work as normal but with the `1` it will break. However, if I change it to `2` so it becomes `namespace: 'api/v2'` it will work completely fine. Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that if your json response returns an empty array only you'll get this error. So for example - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/baras/1/edit. My json response should be returning `post: []` and not just `[]` as this is not the correct format for ember data. Once I changed the json to return `post: []` everything worked as normal.

Guides: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-root

Good read: http://jsonapi.org/